# Junit 4 does not recognize test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I cloned a repository and tried to run a test. Unfortunately, JUnit 4 does not recognize the directory that I added manually

The test GUI says after tries to load the tests:

> No tests were found.
>
> Tests ran to completion.
>
> Empty test suite.

This is my directory with `ExampleUnitTest` that i copypasted by another project (this is a default file that is not questionable that does not work)

[image]

And this is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        testApplicationId "com.commonsware.android.retrofit.test"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
}
```

EDIT as requested here the content of ExampleUnitTest and Run/Debug Configurations.

```
package com.commonsware.android.retrofit;

/**
 * To work on unit tests, switch the Test Artifact in the Build Variants view.
 */
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Run/Debug Configurations
[image]

Comment: can you show your test?

Comment: Please show `ExampleUnitTest`. Make sure it has methods marked with the `@Test` annotation. It might also help if you show the Run Configuration which you are using.

Comment: run/debug added in the main post

Comment: Is your Test Configuration using Android Tests or JUnit? I think it sould be the later.

Comment: I suspect that you have the incorrect type of Run Configuration. The easiest way to create the correct one is to click the run icon to the left of the class or method name in editor window.

Comment: I knew from the beginning the green arrow works, but I need to run dozens of tests! if in gradle I insert in build Config the line : testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"   it runs the instrumented test, I think the system thinks that I am running an instrumentation test instead of a junit one!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. you were right about click the run icon on the the left of the class, it is going to set correctly the run/debug configuration, then I can just change from class to 
"all in module" to make it workable. Pity you are in the comments, I can not even upvote you. thanks

Comment: @trocchietto Added an answer with some additional details.

Comment: upvoted Code-Apprentice. thank you very much.of course feel free to upvote me as well if you like my question:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure Android Studio don't see any test in *Run/Debug Configurations* menu. To do that, click on `Edit Configurations...` option and then check **JUnit** section on the left.

[image]

If there are no tests, click [image], select **JUnit**, select `app` module and `ExampleUnitTest` class. Don't forget to apply changes and then try to run test again.

[image]

If this does not help, please try switching from Release to Debug build variant and ensure there is no stacktrace of the exception in Android Monitor tab.

Comment: I am sorry does not work, I did what you say,  Even indicating the class explicitely and using app and pressing Apply.( also is strange that  you do not need to indicate any class when you start an android studio project with the wizard). I guess is or the directory that is wrong, or I miss something in build.gradle.

Comment: @trocchietto So please show the content of `ExampleUnitTest`, possible that this may cause the problem

Comment: ExampleUnitTest added on the main post, please consider that it works if I run the text from inside the android gui

Comment: @trocchietto The screenshot you provided shows you created configuration for `Android Tests` not `JUnit` as I mentioned. Android Tests is used for Instrumented Unit Test

Comment: so please how can i create a configuration for Junit?

Comment: @trocchietto please refer to updated screenshot, on red color there is marked configuration you created and on green is marked the one that is correct

Comment: I'm glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a Run Configuration manually in the "Edit Configurations" dialog, you should select "JUnit" for local tests and "Android Tests" only for instrumented tests. The easiest way to do this for a single test class or method is to click any of the run icons on the left in editor window. You can also right-click on any class or package in the Project view then select "Run 'Tests in ...". Alternatively you can left-click on a class or package and push Ctrl+Shift+F10.